# Same comment repeating in loop

Tags: wordpress

I have a loop going in my search results page that looks like this:

```
        <tr>              
          <th class="search-note" id="search-note">Last Note</th>
        </tr>    


<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            $rid = get_the_ID();

//Get most recent note
        $args = array(                  
            'post_id' => $rid,                
            'number' => '1',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC'
        );

//Date of last comment 
        $comments = get_comments($args);        
        foreach($comments as $comment) :
          $lastComment = convert_date(($comment->comment_date)) . ' -  <a href="' . get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) . '">' . neat_trim(($comment->comment_content), 100) .  '</a> -- <em>' . ($comment->comment_author) . '</em>';
        endforeach;


         <tr>          
          <td><?php echo $lastComment; ?></td>
        </tr>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The problem is, the last comment it is getting is the same for every row in the results.  So it gets all of the correct information for the comment I want, but it lists that same comment on rows that have no comments on it at all on every row instead of being different per the different post_id.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first I would check to see if $lastComment is actually set, before trying to echo it.  Then, I would unset it after echoing it.  Otherwise it will retain its value from the previous run of the foreach loop.   Something like this, perhaps:

```
<td><?php 
    if(isset($lastComment)) {
        echo $lastComment;
        unset($lastComment);
    } 
?></td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  That seems to work although I thought since it was going trough the loop each time, it would change it to null or "" if it had no value.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: get_comments($args) will return an empty array if there are no comments, which means the script will not enter the foreach loop... leaving $lastComment with its previous value...